# How to connect to an ESP8266 via public address?

Tags: esp8266

Can we connect to an ESP8266 (through the internet) knowing its local and public IP addresses without setting the WiFi modem to which it is connected?

Comment: What do you mean by "setting the WiFi modem"? Why would you need to know a local IP if you know its public IP? What's your overall scenario?

Comment: What is a WiFi modem? Do you mean a firewall that is WiFi AP  capable? If that is the case then you need to create a port forward in the firewall.

Comment: assuming `without setting the WiFi modem` means without configuring port forwarding in your NAT router - then, yes, there are ways to achieve this

Comment: Yes, I mean to be connected to the ESP without configuring port forwarding.

Comment: Jaromanda, would you please explain how it could be done.

Comment: theoretically - [upnp port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461516/esp8266-upnp-port-forwarding-iot) is what you want - of course, your router will need to have UPnP enabled - and I have no idea if the code in the answer actually works :p